# Does the Conjugate Gradient Method provide an eigenvalue estimate?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that we apply a Krylov subspace method to the linear system $A x = b$. For example, if $A$ is symmetric positive-definite, then the Conjugate Gradient method may be used.

I remember that the iterations of Krylov subspace methods also reveal information on the spectrum of $A$, at least an estimate for the largest eigenvalue.

I am searching for a detailed derivation of such an estimate that leads to an implementation.

Comment: You can use the Rayleigh quotient of the current eigenvector estimate to get an eigenvalue estimate.

Comment: Good eigenvalue estimates can be obtained from the equivalence between CG and the Lanczos method. See Section 6.7 (namely 6.7.3) [here](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf). You just need to reconstruct the Jacobi matrix and compute its eigenvalues (or the maximal eigenvalue).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Nice reference.